# Does type theory help us avoid the "defining postulate"?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory

As a personal project, I decided to prove everything I learned in mathematics using formal proofs. The difference between informal proof, which is commonly used by mathematicians, and formal proof is shown in Chapter 3 of the book "[Logic, Mathematics, and Computer Science](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-3223-8)" by Yves Nievergelt.

During the course of this project, I encountered a problem that I will attempt to illustrate below. Let's consider the axiom of pairing:

$$\vdash \forall x\forall y\exists z\forall w(w\in z\leftrightarrow w=x\vee w=y)$$

You can prove that there's only one set $z$ satisfying the previous axiom, that is, you can prove that

$$\vdash \forall x\forall y\exists \color{red}{!}z\forall w(w\in z\leftrightarrow w=x\vee w=y)\,\,\color{red}{(1)}$$

Because of this, it's conventional to denote the set $z$ by $\{x,y\}$. However, according to the book "[Set Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/set-theory/E3A15986642F9C5AA8B13794FEA96CA7)" by András Hajnal (see page 115), an additional axiom is required to formalize this convention. The approach given in this book with regard to the axiom of pairing is as follows:

First you define $\phi(x,y,z):=\forall w(w\in z\leftrightarrow w=x\vee w=y)$. The book calls this the *defining postulate* of the operator $\{\,,\}$.

According to $(1)$, we have $\vdash \forall x\forall y\exists !z\phi (x,y,z)$. Then we add the following axiom: $\vdash \forall x \forall y\phi(x,y,\{x,y\})$. This extension is an effective strict conservative extension (see the Theorem A2.1 of the book).

---

**My question is:** does type theory help us avoid the need to add more axioms for each new definition?

I am looking for a formal language that can express, for example, the axiom of pairing and introduce the set builder notation $\{\,,\}$ without requiring an additional axiom.

Having skimmed through "[Type Theory and Formal Proof](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/type-theory-and-formal-proof/0472640AAD34E045C7F140B46A57A67C)” by Rob Nederpelt, I have the impression that it's possible to achieve this using an extension of Calculus of Constructions denoted by $\lambda D$ in this book. However, since I know nothing about type theory, it's possible that I am misinterpreting its usage.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: The relevant keyword for the process you describe is: definitional expansion. It is a general fact that every definitional expansion of a theory is a conservative extension, proving no new assertions expressible in the original language, and furthermore, every assertion in the new language is provably equivalent to one in the original language. So another way to express your question is: how does type theory handle definitional expansions?

Comment: Isn't introducing a type to represent the term basically analogous to introducing a definitional expansion? To introduce a new notation, one seems to need somehow to define what it is or how it functions. It seems to me that any manner of introducing a term will involve something essentially analogous to the definitional expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, type theory does not need to add new axioms to represent definitions. The basic idea is that the formal language of type theory contains a binding form for terms -- something like:

$\mathsf{let}\; x = e_1 \;\mathsf{in}\; e_2$

This introduces the name $x$ for the expression $e_1$ within the scope of the expression $e_2$.
The judgmental equality rule for this construct is also very simple: we say that $\mathsf{let}\; x = e_1 \;\mathsf{in}\; e_2$ is judgementally equal to $[e_1/x]e_2$ (i.e., substituting $e_1$ for $x$ everywhere in $e_2$).

This corresponds to writing something like "Let $x$ be $e_1$. Now, $e_2$" in mathematical vernacular. Furthermore, when we introduce such a construction, we feel to switch between writing $x$ and $e_1$ without comment (unless it is somehow instructive to note) -- this corresponds to the judgemental equality rule.

One thing to watch out for is that the type-theoretic approach to definitions mimics how the mathematical vernacular uses definitions. However, it is not  precisely the same thing as what you describe in your post (what Joel calls "definitional expansion").

There you prove the *logical proposition*  $\exists! y \in A.\; P(y)$, and use that to *postulate* an *object-language term* $t$ which is  in $A$ and satisfies $P(t)$.

This conjuration of an object from a logical fact is essentially an example of a *definite description*, or the principle of unique choice. This is an extremely powerful operation, and off-the-shelf dependent type theory was not designed to support it because it handled logic differently.

There is a very interesting design landscape here, but for most people the high-order bit is that unique choice is a really useful thing to have if you want your type theory to be the internal language of a topos (which is a pretty good benchmark for "most of mathematics can be formalised in this system").

Comment: Are you saying that one doesn't need to add the axiom because type theory is seen as already having specified all possible types/terms? That would seem to make the type theory situation analogous to what in the first-order logic setting is called the full definitional expansion, where one has added terms for every possible definition--one has closed the language under all possible definitional expansions. In this case, one wouldn't need to "add" any axioms for defined terms, since there is already such a term in the full definitional expansion.

Comment: I think let-binding is not so much the point.  As Joel says, I would argue the point is rather that type theory, unlike set theory, actually has *terms* that already denote all the objects we can construct, so there is no need for definitional expansion.  Let-binding is just introducing an abbreviation for a term that already exists.

Comment: It's true that some versions of dependent type theory don't satisfy the axiom of unique choice unless you postulate it.  But "modern" type theories (if you'll permit that word) do automatically satisfy it, if they follow homotopy type theory in taking the "propositions" to be the subsingleton types.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: if I understand you correctly, you have in mind the introduction of a bunch of constants $c_\phi$ with axioms $\phi(c_\phi)$, one for every formula $\phi(x)$ satisfying $\exists! \phi(x)$. If that's true, then the answer is: that's not an appropriate analogy because it completely obliterates the structure of terms, but type theory thrives on such structure. Let-binding is precisely and only a mechanism for introducing abbreviations. You could add it to ZFC, but it would be useless, since ZFC does not have any term formers, apart from variables.

Comment: No, that's only part of it. The full definitional expansion of a theory also adds new function and predicate symbols (in every arity), closing under definable terms and relations. This is a completely standard model-theoretic construction, known since 1950s. The full definitional expansion is conservative over the original, and indeed every assertion in new language is equivalent to an assertion in the original language. The expansion admits quantifier-elimination, etc. etc. I don't see any obliteration of terms---this is simply an expanded language with its own first-order terms.

Comment: In particular, this technique is from first-order logic, not about set theory specifically, but any first-order theory. In ZFC, certain parts of set theory introduce defined terms, which are very useful when analyzing the constructible hierarchy, since there is a rich theory of indiscernibility there.

Comment: The full definitional expansion is also semantically conservative over the original theory, meaning that every model of the original theory can be extended to a model of the expansion. (Syntactic conservativity, about not proving any new assertions in the old language, does not always imply semantic conservativity, but it does for definitional expansions.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: One key difference is that in the first-order setting, definitional expansion is a genuine, if minor, change of language and theory the theory, while in type theories with let-binding, you’re always still working within a fixed base theory.  Of course since definitional expansions are so strongly equivalent to their original theory, it’s very mathematically inconsequential — but from a foundational point of view, it feels nice to have statements like “we develop mathematics within this fixed theory” a little closer to genuinely true.

Comment: I think that is how people view the definitional expansions, in light of the strong conservativity results. One views the defined terms essentially as abbreviations for notions expressible in the original language and theory, but enabling term denotations as a convenience. I gather this is also the function of let-binding?

Comment: Yes, let-binding is an abbreviation mechanism built into the syntax of type theory. From a computer scientist's pov, it's more convenient to put abbreviations into the theory (rather than the meta-theory), because implementations are easier to trust when they stay close to the formalism.